# How to use Python 3.5.1 with pyenv (on Mac)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyenv

I installed Python 3.5.1 and then ran `pyenv install 3.5.1`, thinking this would point to Python 3.5.1. But that didn't work.

```
MBP-Oct-2016:~ user1$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
MBP-Oct-2016:~ user1$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/user1/.pyenv/version)
  3.5.1
```

How do I get pyenv to make Python 3.5.1 the default version of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: Don't touch `~/.pyenv/version` directly. That's not the recommended way.

1. **Initialize `pyenv`** by putting the following content in your shell's init file. (`~/.bash_profile` for Bash on macOS, `~/.zshrc` for ZSH).

   ```sh
   export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

   if command -v pyenv &>/dev/null; then
     eval "$(pyenv init -)"
   fi
   if command -v pyenv-virtualenv &>/dev/null; then
     eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
   fi
   ```
2. Open a **new** interactive shell, set Python 3.5.1 as the default Python with following command,

   ```sh
   pyenv global 3.5.1
   ```

References

- [Initialize `pyenv` from `README.md` in the official repo](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout)